# What is the typical technique of loading dynamic elements from the server and/or client?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Let's say I have a simple form setup.  I can dynamically add the below element as mant times to a form via javascript.

```
<div class="aComplicateDiv">
    <input type="text" name="myValue">
</div>
```

Now let's say we save these values, and then want to edit them.  I can query the DB on the edit page and then from the server side, display the div with the input fields.

My issue is, when I'm adding this div, im using javascript to build the elements. However, when I display these elements on the server side, I'm using php.  Seems to be repetitive, especially if I want to change the elements.  I can however, from the server side, call javascript functions that pass in values to build it via javascript on the edit page, but that seems to not be the correct process. Any insight would be great on if there is a better approach or not.

Comment: you COULD use a javascript templating approach, such as AngularJS, to do both, but there is nothing wrong with the way you currently do it

Comment: Are you familiar with AJAX (or asynchronous calls in general)? There are ton of resources for this.

Comment: Please tell me what magic you use to display those elements on the server side.

Comment: Seriously, there is no right or wrong. Go with whatever works in your use case.

Answer (score 0):

The approach I mainly use in that kind situations (especially when the repeating part gets more complicated):

In PHP (extremly simplified):

```
function addRow($index, $data) {
    echo '<div class="aComplicateDiv" id="row-'.$index.'">
              <input type="text" name="myValue['.$index.']" value="'.htmlspecialchars($data).'">
          </div>';
}

foreach($dataFromDb as $row) {
    addRow($row['id'], $row['value']);
}
addRow('TEMPLATE', '');
```

In Javascript ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kNfud/))

```
var nextIndex = 2; // Find a way to calculate this
$('#add').click(function() {
    // Append a clone of the template to a temporary div
    // From that div we can get the html-content
    var html = $('<div>').append(
        $('#row-TEMPLATE').clone()
    ).html().replace(/TEMPLATE/g, nextIndex++);
    $('#row-TEMPLATE').before(html);
});
```